# Method for converting hex to decimal--program incorrect when a non-hex number is entered

Tags: java

I have composed a program that converts a hex number to decimal.  For the most part it works, However, when I input a non-hexadecimal string, it computes that value correctly and displays it as a non-hexadecimal number, but it also jumps to the next line and outputs it as well.  I think this is the part of the code which is problematic:

```
for (int i = 0; i < hexInput.length (); i++){
   int value = hexValue (hexInput.charAt(i));

    if (value == -1){
    System.out.println ("You must enter a hexadecimal number.  Try again 
    please.");  
}
```

This correctly identifies incorrect input and the `println` statement is executed.  However, it also executes the next line of code:

```
System.out.println("The hexadecimal number, "  + hexInput + ", in base 10,  is " + hexDecimalConversion (hexInput) + "." );
```

Consequently, if an incorrect digit--say `j`--is entered, the result is:

> You must enter a hexadecimal number.  Try again please.
>   The hexadecimal number, j, in base 10,  is -1.

I want to get rid of the second line, and resume the loop so the user can enter another number.

I just need to know how to resume the program from the beginning, without the last line of code been executed, when an incorrect digit(s) has been entered.

Here is the entire program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HexBinaryConversion {

    //method takes string as input, converts string to decimal
    //using hexvalue method.

    public static long hexDecimalConversion(String hexInput) {

        long value = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < hexInput.length(); i++) {
            value = value * 16 + hexValue(hexInput.charAt(i));
        }
        return value;

    } //end of HexDecimalConversion method.

    //method takes character as input and converts it to
    //appropriate hexadecimal value.

    public static int hexValue(char ch) {
        switch (ch) {
            case '0':
                return 0;
            case '1':
                return 1;
            case '2':
                return 2;
            case '3':
                return 3;
            case '4':
                return 4;
            case '5':
                return 5;
            case '6':
                return 6;
            case '7':
                return 7;
            case '8':
                return 8;
            case '9':
                return 9;
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
                return 10;
            case 'b':
            case 'B':
                return 11;
            case 'c':
            case 'C':
                return 12;
            case 'd':
            case 'D':
                return 13;
            case 'e':
            case 'E':
                return 14;
            case 'f':
            case 'F':
                return 15;
            default:
                return -1;
        }

    } //end of hexValue method.

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Scanner stdin = new Scanner (System.in);
       String hexInput = "0";

        while (!hexInput.equalsIgnoreCase ("x")){

       System.out.println("Enter a hexadecimal number or enter x  to terminate 
       the program: ");
       hexInput = stdin.next();
       if (hexInput.equalsIgnoreCase ("x")) {

       System.out.println ("Thank you for using this program.");
       break;
       }

       long answer = hexDecimalConversion (hexInput);

       for (int i = 0; i < hexInput.length (); i++){
       int value = hexValue (hexInput.charAt(i));

       if (value == -1){

        System.out.println ("You must enter a hexadecimal number.  Try again 
       please."); 

       break;
       } 
       }

       System.out.println("The hexadecimal number, "  + hexInput + ", in base 
       10,  is " + answer + "." );


        }//end of while loop.   

    }//end of main ().

}//end of class.
```

And this is the output:

```
run:
Enter a hexadecimal number or enter x  to terminate the program: 
a

The hexadecimal number, a, in base 10,  is 10.

Enter a hexadecimal number or enter x  to terminate the program: 
45

The hexadecimal number, 45, in base 10,  is 69.

Enter a hexadecimal number or enter x  to terminate the program: 
j

You must enter a hexadecimal number.  Try again please.          
The hexadecimal number, j, in base 10,  is -1.

**************************incorrect line***************************

Enter a hexadecimal number or enter x  to terminate the program: 
ll

The hexadecimal number, ll, in base 10,  is 17. 

Enter a hexadecimal number or enter x  to terminate the program: 
x
Thank you for using this program.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 36 seconds)
```

Comment: Please fix your code so it would compile (remove linebreaks inside strings), and format your code properly - indent code inside `{ }`.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the result even when you have invalid values. You test for -1, print an error message, and the flow continues to `System.out.println`, and it should never get there.

Change this:

```
    if (value == -1){
        System.out.println ("You must enter a hexadecimal number.  Try again please."); 
        break;
    } 
}
System.out.println("The hexadecimal number, "  + hexInput + ", in base 10,  is " + answer + "." );
```

To this:

```
    if (value == -1){
        System.out.println ("You must enter a hexadecimal number.  Try again please."); 
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("The hexadecimal number, "  + hexInput + ", in base 10,  is " + answer + "." );
    }
}
```

And a tip: don't use a lookup table for converting Hex to Decimal. You can use regex to remove unwanted chars, and parseInt to convert directly:

```
int intValue = Integer.parseInt(hexString.replaceAll("[^a-fA-F0-9]", ""), 16);
```

Test for **x** before parsing, and you are done.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  But something is still amiss.  I made the suggested changes but this is the output:                                                                                                   Enter a hexadecimal number or enter x  to terminate the program: 
j
You must enter a hexadecimal number.  Try again please.
Enter a hexadecimal number or enter x  to terminate the program: 
45
The hexadecimal number, 45, in base 10,  is 69.
The hexadecimal number, 45, in base 10,  is 69.
Enter a hexadecimal number or enter x  to terminate the program:

Comment: You probably still have `System.out.println("The hexadecimal number...` twice... Delete the last one.